# HTML input string with onclick function taking two parameters - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if the question wording is bad, I'm not really sure how to describe it.

I have a button which, when clicked, does this:

```
function Save(id, projectID) {
        var url = "@Url.Content("~/Config/Detail?id=")" + id + "&projectID=" + projectID;
    var _options = {
        area: ['590px', '385px'],
        content: url
    }
    tools.openTopPage(_options);
};
```

If I manually enter values for `id` and `project ID` in the second line, it works, so I know there's no problem in this function.

However, when the function is called from an input string it doesn't work.

The string is here (being put into a htmlArray):

```
    htmlArray.push(
    "<td class='text-center'>
       <input type='button' class='form-btn' value='修改' 
           onclick=Save(" + item.id + ", " + item.projectID + ") />
       <input type='button' id='btn-delete' class='form-btn'
           value='删除' onclick=Delete(" + item.id + ") />
    </td>");
```

I thought the problem was due to the way the input string breaks and has variables `item.id` and `item.projectID` put into the Save() function, however it doesn't even work if I keep it simple. For example, the following doesn't work either:

```
htmlArray.push(
    "<td class='text-center'>
       <input type='button' class='form-btn' value='修改' 
           onclick=Save(6, 3) />
       <input type='button' id='btn-delete' class='form-btn'
           value='删除' onclick=Delete(" + item.id + ") />
    </td>");
```

The values 6 and 3 which I have used are the values I would expect to be given if using `item.id` and `item.projectID`.

Most interesting is that the HTML renders the same in the browser in both cases. The result looks like this:

[image]

So surely the issue is somewhere around the Save() function, but I don't know where.

If I simplify the Save() function to take only one parameter it works (e.g. `"Save(" + item.id + ")"` will work fine), so this is what leads me to believe it's messing up when dealing with two parameters.

Any input much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: onclick ="save(6, '', 3)" = "" is the problem, fix it

Comment: Check your console for more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
onclick="save('6','3')"
```

**"** after 6, make issue

Try

```
onclick="save('6','3')"
```

**"** after 6, make issue

**"** and **'** make issue in JavaScript

last option is:

```
var parameters=String("'" + item.id + "','"+item.projectID+"'");
```

use this as

```
htmlArray.push(
    "<td class='text-center'>
       <input type='button' class='form-btn' value='修改' 

           onclick=Save("+parameters+") />

       <input type='button' id='btn-delete' class='form-btn'
           value='删除' onclick=Delete(" + item.id + ") />
    </td>");
```

looks stupid but I used it many times.

If any other option,welcome !!!

Comment: I've tried loads of variations and none of it works. As I said, Save(6, 3) doesn't work, whereas Save(3) is fine, so it seems to only have a problem when I put more than one parameter in. In this case, the only additional punctuation I'm using is a comma, so I don't see how the quotation mark is the issue.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I managed to solve it last night using your advice, just after I posted the previous comment, but I couldn't comment again until now because stackoverflow suddenly became unavailable (probably because I'm in China... ha). Thanks for your advice, it worked, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/6h73pxcv/

```
<input type='button' class='form-btn' value='修改' onclick="Save(6, 3)" />
```

onclick needs to have quotes around it. Also make sure "Save()" is globally available

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is with multiple parameter why not use only one and threat item as a object? So instead of breaking items you could pass it all.

```
function Save(item) {
        var url = "@Url.Content("~/Config/Detail?id=")" + item.id + "&projectID=" + item.projectID;
    var _options = {
        area: ['590px', '385px'],
        content: url
    }
    tools.openTopPage(_options);
};
```

and in htmlArray:

```
htmlArray.push(
    "<td class='text-center'>
       <input type='button' class='form-btn' value='修改' 
           onclick=Save(" + item + ") />
       <input type='button' id='btn-delete' class='form-btn'
           value='删除' onclick=Delete(" + item.id + ") />
    </td>");
```

I know it is not what you want but is another way of thinking and can help you further.

**UPDATE**

Maybe if you switch some single and double quotes inside your htmlArray you may achieve your goal.

```
htmlArray.push(
        '<td class="text-center">
           <input type="button" class="form-btn" value="修改" 
               onclick="Save(' + item + ')" />
           <input type="button" id="btn-delete" class="form-btn"
               value="删除" onclick="Delete(' + item.id + ')" />
        </td>');
```

Comment: I've tried this already. I tried making a variable {/// saveString = item.id + ", " + item.projectID ///} then used that single variable in the input string. However, this has exactly the same problematic result when rendering in the browser. It once again comes up as {/// onclick ="save(6, '', 3)" = "" ///} Most interesting is that when I call {/// alert(saveString) ///} it prints 6, 3 , so that part is correct.

Comment: @StuartAitken I made an update. Maybe if you change some quotes, you could achieve your goal.

Comment: All solved now, and yeah it was a problem with the quotes. Cheers!

Comment: @StuartAitken Glad could help ya! Good luck in your further projects! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `ES6` standard

```
htmlArray.push(
  `<td class='text-center'>
     <input type='button' class='form-btn' value='修改' 
       onclick="Save('${item.id}, '${item.projectID}');" />
     <input type='button' id='btn-delete' class='form-btn'
       value='删除' onclick="Delete('${item.id}');" />
  </td>`);
```

Hope this will help you.